# Is it possible to pipe a list of files to RMDIR on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, pipe, dir

I am writing a batch file for the Windows command prompt to delete all directories matching a certain expression.

I am first using `DIR` to return a plain list of directories matching the expression. I would like to pipe each line of output into the RMDIR command, like this:

```
DIR *.delete /A:D /B /S | RMDIR /S /Q
```

However the above command doesn't seem to work. I don't fully understand why this doesn't work and would be grateful to anyone who can offer an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following in your batch file:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.delete /A:D /B /S') DO RMDIR /S /Q %%a
```

This uses the `FOR` command to loop through the output of a given command (in this case `dir *.delete /A:D /B /S`, and for each item returned it will run the command specified with the DO statement, `RMDIR /S /Q`. The item is referred to by the variable `%%a`.

The reason it doesn't work simply piping the `DIR` output into `RMDIR` is because you're sending the whole output (multiple lines) all at once as a single parameter to `RMDIR`. The `FOR` command breaks down this output, iterates through each item and then sends that to `RMDIR` one by one.